# Check if Apache is installed on a Ubuntu machine

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp

Is there a way to check *if* Apache is installed on my [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) machine?

I am trying to install `LAMP` on my Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use the below commands to check if Apache is installed or not:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
```

or

```
apache2 -v
```

Answer (score 4):

Command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
```

Output:

```
apache2            install
apache2-bin        install
apache2-data       install
apache2-utils      install
```

Command:

```
apache2 -v
```

Output

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-10-08T13:31:25
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for a more generic approach, not depending on dpkg

```
command -v apache2
```

There's a post on this subject:
[How can I check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)